# Disabling 2nd monitor causes 1st monitor to have a lag

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with latest updates. I run two monitors normally. Sometimes I want to use only one monitor. I open the monitor program and uncheck the 2nd monitor to disable it. I save the settings.

The monitor that is left enabled begins to have delay issues. For example, when I open Chrome and try to navigate the internet, there seems to be a 4 second delay (timed it) between clicks/typing etc. I disabled all my plugins because I thought that's what it was, but this didn't help. When I reenable the 2nd monitor, everything works fine again, there is no delay on my clicks.

Has anyone had this happen to them? I have tried restarting the computer after disabling one monitor, but this didn't help either.